# SQL trigger difference

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using  Oracle sql trigger but I'm not able to understand the difference between:

```
• SET myVar := (…);
```

and

```
• SET myVar = (…);
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The first assigns a variable.  The second is used inside an `update` statement (usually).

Comment: `SET`? Are you really using Oracle or is it part of the UPDATE statement?

Comment: Both are invalid in Oracle PL/SQL